# Uncaught InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch

when i used the sencha touch2.2.1,i met a question.
In the viewer:

```
items: [{
    id: 'mapCanvas',
    xtype:'map',
    useCurrentLocation: true,
}]
```

In the controller:

```
var map= Ext.getCmp('mapCanvas');
console.dir(map);
var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(25,118),
            });
marker.setMap(map);
```

report the error:

Uncaught InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map, and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama

I can see the map,but i can't see the marker, and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : position,
                setMap : map
            });
```

It worked for me!

Comment: what's the diff between setMap and map then?

Comment: Jip, I can confirm this worked for me as well .... but I have no idea why? Some more information would be great!

Answer (score 5):

`map` is not an instance of google map .

```
var map= Ext.getCmp('mapCanvas').getMap(); // add getMap() here to get the map instance
console.dir(map);
var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25,118),
});
marker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the marker to the map directly by using the marker's setMap() method, as shown in the example below:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    title:"Hello World!"
});

// To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
marker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

var map is a HTML element you need an instance of the google.maps.Map Object

```
var map = google.maps.Map(document.querySelector("#mapCanvas"),{
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.027872, -104.655278),
      zoom: 12
    });
```

then....

```
var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(25,118),
  map: map
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `marker.setMap` method expects the argument to be a google.maps.Map object. This is not one of those:

```
var map= Ext.getCmp('mapCanvas');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var  latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
     position = new google.maps.LatLng(25,118),
     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : position,
            map : map
        }); 

latlngbounds.extend(position);

map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

Here `map` is the rendered `google.map.Map` instance

Answer (score 0):

mapCanvas is Ext map component which holds the map instance.

```
var map= Ext.getCmp('mapCanvas');
console.dir(map);
var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25,118),
              });
marker.setMap(map.getMap());
```