# Why isn't this an instance of map of google.maps.Map? InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map;

Tags: javascript, google-maps, object, google-maps-api-3

I am getting the error `Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama` on a google map web page. I then read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003952/uncaught-invalidvalueerror-setmap-not-an-instance-of-map) elsewhere here on Stack Overflow which told me I need an instance of the `google.maps.MAP` object. I thought that by calling that object in order to initialize the map that I would be calling that object.

Previously, I got the error `i is not defined` so I moved the `createMarker` function into the `$.getJSON` function where it has local scope.

Do I need to call `google.mapsMap` somewhere else?

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Hello World</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <ul id="list"></ul>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function initialize(){
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38, -78),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'https://opendata.howardcountymd.gov/resource/96q9-qbh7.json';
    initialize();
    $.getJSON(url, function (data){
        $.each(data, function(i, field) {
            $('#list').append("<li>" + data[i].location.longitude + " & " + data[i].location.latitude + "</li>");
            createMarker(data);

            function createMarker (data) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].location.latitude, data[i].location.longitude),
                    map: map,
                    title: field.crossroad
                });
            };
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The map variable that is an instance of a `google.maps.Map` is local to the `initialize` function.  The map variable in the `createMarker` function is undefined. One option: define the variable in the global scope:

```
var map;
```

then just initialize it in the `initialize` function:

```
function initialize(){
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38, -78),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp);
};
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9zy1zd61/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38, -78),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'https://opendata.howardcountymd.gov/resource/96q9-qbh7.json';
  initialize();
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, field) {
      $('#list').append("<li>" + data[i].location.longitude + " & " + data[i].location.latitude + "</li>");
      createMarker(data);

      function createMarker(data) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].location.latitude, data[i].location.longitude),
          map: map,
          title: field.crossroad
        });
      };
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Hello World</h1>

<div id="map"></div>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

[Another option would be to return the `map` from the initialize function](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9zy1zd61/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is definitely with js not being able to access the initialized map. For me in an angular project, the 'this.gmap' was giving an issue as 'this' was conflicting with some internal 'this' in the 'geocoder.geocode' stub. After breaking my head over this issue for a couple of hours, 'let that = this" outside the stub gave me access to the map initialized in another method.

```
        ngOnInit() {
        this.gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
          center: { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng },
          zoom: this.zoom
        });
        this.getGeocode();
      }
       getGeocode() {
        debugger;
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        let element= "Delhi";
        let that = this;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': element }, function (results, status) {
          console.dir(results);
          console.dir(status);
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            that.results = results;
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
          that.setMarker();
        });
      }

      setMarker() {
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: this.results[0].geometry.location,
          map: this.gmap
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For IE,
If you are using `InfoBox` to display `google maps marker`. Please make sure that you put `type="text/javascript"` in the InfoBox script tag.
Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../infobox.js"></script>
```